# Inserting variable into jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to pass a variable to a selector. It keeps giving me back 0 from the loop I am running around it. I can see the results of my loop in the console which is what I want, but the value is not being applied to the height. My code is below. On `else if (key === "height")`, my selector of `$("div.element")` is not getting the right value. I keep getting 0px which I do not want.

```
var count = 0;
$.each(ResultJSON, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value, function(key, value) {
        if (key === "categories") {
                categories.push(value);
        } else if (key === "itemid") {
                $("div#" + count + "").append('<img class="elementImage" src="/mob/images/' + value + '.jpg" />');
        } else if (key === "height") {
                console.log(value);
                $("div.element").css("height", + value + "px" +"");
        }
    });
count++;
});
```

Comment: what `console.log(value);` gives you? Because that syntax [works](http://jsfiddle.net/ScyZ3/) (at least in firefox)

Comment: It gives me my values from my php script.

Comment: What is inside `count`? Where do you initialize it? How do you update it?

Comment: I added the counter, sorry forgot that.

Comment: Probably because it lacks the `ResultJSON` object and the HTML structure so it is very hard to debug.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/F28GC/1/ narrow down your code.

Comment: Likely case is you expected `$("div.element")` to select some single specific element when in reality it selects all divs with said class.

Comment: I do want it to select all divs with that class.

Comment: Why are you doing that inside of an each then? wouldn't that be a complete waste, since each iteration that has a height will override what happened previously?

Comment: *"It gives me my values from my php script."* And... said values are what?

Comment: This is confusing. What does `value` refer to in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out.

I wasn't including a count on my selector for when my key was === to height.

```
var count = 0;
$.each(ResultJSON, function(key, value) {
        $.each(value, function(key, value) {
                if (key === "categories") {
                        categories.push(value);
                } else if (key === "itemid") {
                        $("div#" + count + "").append('<img class="elementImage" src="/mob/images/' + value + '.jpg" />');
                } else if (key === "height") {
                        $("div#" + count + "").css("height",value);
                }
        });
count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a typo?

```
$("div.element").css("height", + value + "px" +"");
```

Should be

```
$("div.element").css("height",value + "px" +"");
```

Comment: no - `+ value` is simply a positive value, if value is a number

Comment: The unary `+` operator also invokes the internal `ToNumber` algorithm.